# Using eval() with a custom global

Tags: javascript, eval, global

Is there a way to specify which object to use for **global** when invoking `eval()`?

(I'm not asking how to do global eval().)

This is not working but this illustrates what I would like:

```
var pseudoGlobal = {};
eval("x = 12", pseudoGlobal);
pseudoGlobal.x; // 12
```

The point is that real global bindings are not affected by implicit variable declaration (i.e. without **var** keywords) in the code eval()'ed.

As for `eval.call(pseudoGlobal, "x=12")` or `eval.apply(pseudoGlobal, ["x=12"])`, some interpreters wont allow it.

Comment: The intent is to create an isolated/controlled/secure execution environment within Javascript itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, of course, substitute default object for *assigning* a property value, like in

```
with (pseudoGlobal) eval("x=12")
```

but not for *creating* a propery. If a property is not found in the current stack of execution contexts, it's created in the global object. That's all there is to it.
You might try some weird things, also:

```
//global code
var globalvars = {};
for (i in this)
    globalvars[i] = null;
with (pseudoGlobal) 
    eval("x=12")
for (i in this)
    if (!(i in globalvars))
{
    pseudoGlobal[i] = this[i];
    delete this[i];
}
```

If you care about global bindings, try:

```
var globalvars = {};
for (i in this)
    globalvars[i] = this[i];
with (globalvars) 
    eval("x=12")
```

this way the bindings will be changed in globalvars. Note, that shallow copy will prevent only one level of bingings to change.

Comment: Regarding your second code block, this does not prevent a script to change bindings in the real global object.

Comment: I took your question at face value, but still not all is lost... Updated the answer

Comment: And if I do `eval('"use strict";' + code)`, while it constrains the code that can be eval()'ed, this prevent from additional bindings to be created in global scope. This leaves us with possible mutations of level-2+ bindings.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no built-in way to do this.**

There are two solutions that come to mind:

- Prefix all assignments in the `eval`ed code. i.e., instead of `x = 12`, you would have to do something like `o.x = 12`.
- Write your own Javascript interpreter that sandboxes the script and returns an object with all the assigned variables.

Comment: Too bad we can't create our own execution environment with Javascript.  There must exists some good reason for Javascript to prevent this. I have the feeling that it's a little bit more complicated than I think (Prototype chains? Constructors? Native functions?).